# What addins provide javascript extract method refactoring with Visual Studio?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2010, refactoring, visual-studio-addins, visual-studio-extensions

I need to perform extract method refactoring on my javascript files in visual studio 2010.

In visual studio, the Refactor menu is hidden and the CTRL+R,M macro does not work.

However, renaming variables CTRL+R,R works. I need extract method.

Also, I have R#8 and I am stunned that it does not support refactoring in javascript! The menus are disabled while in a JS file.

I have looked around and could only find [Onyx Dev Tools](http://www.techinceptions.com/odt/features.html); while free, it actually messed up the javascript when i tried it. So it was not working correctly.

**What addins can refactor my javascript in Visual Studio (2010)?**

Comment: I believe CodeRush does.